# How do I align a div background with the bottom of its contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background I want to use that contrasts nicely with my content, except for the bottom 25% or so of the image. How can I align that 25% position with either the bottom of the content, or a set distance from the bottom of the div? The height of the content varies with page width, and the background has size cover

HTML

```
<div class="firstPanel">content here</div>
```

CSS

```
.firstPanel {
    background-image: URL("path-to-background");
    background-position: 50% 70%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Comment: The selector should be `.first.panel`

Comment: Looks like autocorrect changed it, fixed

Comment: Missed the one in the HTML when I fixed the one in CSS

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood in your question,in the CSS you would add this :

```
margin-bottom:25%;
```

This specifies a margin in percent of the width of the containing element.

Comment: This gets me closer, but it still overlaps when the window is narrower and text starts wrapping, and I'd like the space to be smaller than that gives when the window is wider

Comment: Try adding this to the CSS too : `position:relative;z-index:1;`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do much besides cause the div to draw on top of another section. Changing margin to padding and using `margin-bottom: calc(250px - 25%)` with a media query to keep the value < 0 fixes the large space, but what can I do when it is narrow?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in css file

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It clears all the unavoidable space from page.

Comment: I have 'body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }'